# How to display all entries that have had a box ticked since a particlar date

Tags: mysql, sap

Good afternoon,

I would be very grateful is someone would be able to offer some assistance to a query I have regarding some SQL I'm needing to implement.

In our database we have a range of customers that have specific properties/category tick boxes associated with them. We're wanting to display a list of all customers that have a certain tick box selected/ticked since a set date. This date is 05-07-17. Would this be possible? Kind of lost as how to display this. Se screenshot below..

[image: properties list associated with customer account]

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. For starters, do you record the date when the box is checked in your system? What tables are involved? How are they connected?

Answer (score 1):

Select customer_field_names from database WHERE date_column >= '2017-05-07' AND tick_mark_field is NOT null;

That should show all listed fields where the date is at least 05/07/2017 and the check mark box is filled in, in some way. This assumes that they are in the same table.

Comment: Hi mate, cheers for the suggestion but I have just noticed this query and perhaps the one I was trying is returning results of any updates made to the customer account and not updates to this particular tick box (I hope this makes sense?).

Comment: Then likely you do not have null, but some other character in the tick box. You will have to check it for value then. Chang tick_mark_field = character.

Comment: Hey, yes this is the case. Blank = 'N' and tick = 'Y'. When searching on the date I am using T0.[UpdateDate] which is the 'date of update' - it just seems when im inputting the date im interested since (5th July), it is returning any old updates made to the customer account and not specific to the tick property.